# How to use outer apply in Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark sql. I am in a situation to convert existing sql query to spark sql.
My existing sql query contains outer apply function which needs to work in spark sql. What is the alternative for Outer apply in Spark sql?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

`OUTER APPLY` is just a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Will the Performance be same ? when we use Left outer join instead Outer apply?

Comment: Yep.  They are equivalent from a Spark perspective.  There are always ways to optimize joins in Spark though, but it depends on your use case.  By the way if you like the answer, remember to upvote it for others.

Comment: They aren't remotely the same thing.  Outer apply() allows an embedded select statement to access the outer query's data, and it allows you to do cool stuff like "select top 1 where..." in order to avoid excessive records being returned.  

Here's a link to examples using T-SQL: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Answer (score 6):

You can do a `OUTER APPLY` with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( query )`.

Here a link to the official documentation including examples at the bottom:
[JOIN (Databricks SQL)](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html)