# Cross Join, Compare Values, and Select Closest Match - More Efficient Way?

Tags: sql, row-number, cross-join

I have two tables with 2 columns. I cross join and subtract the values. I then find the row_number ordered by the subtraction and choose where row = 1. I'm finding the t2.id that has the closest val to t1.id

These tables are quite large. Is the row_number function doing a lot of extra unneeded work by ordering everything after 1? I only need the lowest ranked row.. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

Table 1

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 0.123456 |
| A2 | 1.123456 |
| A3 | -0.712345 |

Table 2

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | 0.065432 |
| B2 | 1.654321 |
| B3 | -0.654321 |

```
--find the t2.id with the closest value to t1.id's val
with cj as (
select 
  t1.id, t2.id,  
  row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by abs(t1.val - t2.val)) end as rw
 from t1
 cross join t2
)
select * from cj where rw = 1
```

Comment: Alternatively, I'm doing this in databricks, so is there a more efficient way of doing this in python? Maybe pandas or graphql or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run this faster - it depends on how many rows are in t1, t2, and how much flexibility you have to add indexes etc.

As @Chris says, sorting (especially sorting many times) can be a killer. As the cost of sorting increases exponentially (geometrically?) with the amount of values you are sorting, it gets increasingly worse the more you have. If t2 only had two rows, then sorting is easy and your original method would probably be the most efficient. However, if t2 has many rows, then it becomes much much harder. And then if t1 has many rows, and you're doing a sort for every row, that also multiplies the cost.

As such, for testing purposes, I have used 1,000 rows in each of t1 and t2 below.

Below I compare several approaches and indicators of speed and processing. )(Spoiler alert) if you *can* pre-sort it (like in @Chris' suggestion) then you can get some big improvements.

I don't use databricks (sorry) and cannot measure speeds/etc on them. Therefore the below is written and tested in SQL server - but can be modified to work in databricks pretty easily I would guess. I think the main difference is `OUTER APPLY` used here - I believe in Databricks that will be an INNER JOIN LATERAL (e.g., [How to use outer apply in Spark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561455/how-to-use-outer-apply-in-spark-sql) - but note I think they got it wrong. OUTER APPLY is equivalent to INNER JOIN LATERAL, while CROSS APPLY is equivalent to LEFT JOIN LATERAL).

I created the two tables and filled them with 1,000 rows each.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (A_id nvarchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, val decimal(10,8));
CREATE TABLE #t2 (B_id nvarchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, val decimal(10,8));
```

**Original approach - sort all rows**

Your original query takes very few data reads, but the cost is the amount of sorting it needs to do. Because ROW_NUMBER() sorts *all* the rows, and then you only take 1, this is your major cost (as @Chris says).

```
-- Original query
with cj as (
select 
  #t1.A_id, #t2.B_id,  
  row_number() over (partition by #t1.A_id order by abs(#t1.val - #t2.val)) as rw
 from #t1
 cross join #t2
)
select * from cj where rw = 1;
```

On my computer, this took 1600ms of CPU time.

**Approach 2 - taking the MIN() value**

However, as you only need the minimum row, there is no need to really sort the other rows. Taking a 'min' only requires a scan through the data once for each data point in t1, and pick the smallest value.

However, once you have the smallest value, you then need to refer to t2 again to get the relevant t2 IDs.

In other words, the logic of this is

- spend less time determining only the smallest absolute difference (instead of sorting them all)
- spend more reads and more time finding which value(s) of t2 get that absolute difference

```
-- Using MIN() to find smallest difference
with cj as (
select 
  #t1.A_id, #t1.val,
  MIN(abs(#t1.val - #t2.val)) AS minvaldif
 from #t1
 cross join #t2
 GROUP BY #t1.A_id, #t1.val
 )
select cj.A_ID,
    #t2.B_id
FROM    cj
        CROSS JOIN #t2
WHERE   abs(cj.val - #t2.val) = minvaldif;
```

This took my computer about half the time of the original - about 800ms of computer time - but more than doubles the amount of data reads it does. Note also that it can return several rows if (say) there are repeats of values in t2.

**Approach 3 - lateral join**

In this case, you do a lateral join (in SQL Server, it's an 'OUTER APPLY') to select just the 1 minimum value you need. Similar to above, you find the min value, but you do it individually for each row in t1. Therefore you need to do 1000 'min' values rather than 1000 sorts.

```
-- Lateral join with min difference
SELECT  #t1.A_id, t2_calc.B_id
    FROM    #t1
            OUTER APPLY 
                (SELECT TOP (1) #t2.B_Id
                FROM #T2
                ORDER BY abs(#t1.val - #t2.val)
                ) AS t2_calc;
```

This is the most efficient so far - with few reads and only 300ms of compute time. If you cannot add indexes, this is probably the best you could do.

**Option 4 - pre-sort the data with an index**

If you can pre-sort the data using an index, then you can boost your efficiency by a lot.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #IX_t2_val ON #t2 (val);
```

The 'gotcha' is that even if you have an index on t2.val, databases will have a problem with `min(abs(t1.val - t2.val))` - they will usually still need to read all the data rather than use the index.

However, you can use the logic you identified in your question - that min(abs(difference)) value is the one where t1.val is closest to t2.val.

In the method below

1. For every t1.val, find the closest t2 row that is less than or
   equal to it, but not over
2. Also find, for every t1.val, the closest t2 row that is above it
3. Then using your logic in the original answer, find the one of these that is the closest.

This also uses lateral views

```
-- Using indexes
with cj as 
        (SELECT #t1.A_id, #t1.val AS A_val, t2_lessthan.B_id, t2_lessthan.val AS B_val
            FROM    #t1
                    CROSS APPLY 
                        (SELECT TOP (1) #t2.B_Id, #t2.val
                        FROM #T2
                        WHERE #t2.val <= #t1.val
                        ORDER BY #t2.val DESC
                        ) AS t2_lessthan

        UNION ALL
        SELECT  #t1.A_id, #t1.val AS A_val, t2_greaterthan.B_id, t2_greaterthan.val AS B_val
            FROM    #t1
                    CROSS APPLY 
                        (SELECT TOP (1) #t2.B_Id, #t2.val
                        FROM #T2
                        WHERE #t2.val > #t1.val
                        ORDER BY #t2.val
                        ) AS t2_greaterthan     
        ),
    cj_rn AS
        (SELECT A_id, B_id,
                row_number() over (partition by A_id order by abs(A_val - B_val)) as rw
            FROM cj
        )
    select * from cj_rn where rw = 1;
```

Compute time: 4ms.

For each value in t1, it simply does 2 index seeks in t2, and 'sorts' the two value (which is very easy). As such, in this case, it is orders of magnitude faster.

So... really the best approach is if you can pre-sort the data (in this case by adding indexes) and then make sure you take advantage of that sort.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Can method 4 be applied if we have multiple `val` columns?

Comment: Do you mean that there are multiple tables and you want to repeat this process a number of times? Or (more probably, from the sound of it) that t2 has multiple val columns you want to compare? And if it's the latter, do the columns operate independently, or that you want to take the difference of all values, then take the one with the minimum sum of differences?

Comment: Unfortunately, the minimum sum of differences. Which I think probably makes any ordering solution not work? I've been using `abs(t1.val1-t2.val1) + abs(t1.val2-t2.val2)...` for 30 columns. I could use a different cost formula if there's a better way of doing it

Comment: Sorry - I think you're right, that won't work: (for example, based on your description) the best solution for a row in t1 may be a row in t2 with 29 differences of 0, and one with a comparatively larger difference - but the total is still lower than other rows in t2 with 30 difference values all close to 0. I think therefore you'd need to calculate the difference for every possible pair, or find some algorithm to lessen the space - but it would still be very inefficient. You may find some info if you search for 'taxicab geometry' or 'manhattan distances' but I didn't have much luck.

Comment: I'll leave my answer here - although it may not be the best. I would suggest modifying option 3 (e.g., using a lateral view) if you can code it into databricks. This basically does the answer with as few other calculations as possible e.g., it starts with first row in t1, calculates the differences against all rows in t2 and takes the one with the smallest difference.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like databricks will allow this. `Expressions referencing the outer query are not supported outside of WHERE/HAVING clauses`. I do have access to redshirt, so I might end up using method 3 in there. For anyone interested in the topic I'm going to post a python version of this question too

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where procedural code is better than the set logic used in SQL.  If you get a cursor on both table1 & table2 (separately) both ordered by val, you can take advantage of the ordering to not compare EVERY combination of As and Bs.

Using Table2 as the primary, prime the 'pump' by reading the first (lowest) value from Table1 into variable FirstA and the second value from Table1 into variable SecondA.

First, loop while next B < FirstA. Output B & FirstA, because every A thereafter will be farther away because the list is ordered.

Now form a loop using the Table2 cursor, read each B value in turn.  While B > SecondA, move SecondA to FirstA and read another value from table1 into SecondA or end of cursor.  Now B is between FirstA and SecondA; one of those two is closest, compare the abs(difference) and output the lowest and proceed to the next loop iteration.

That's all there is to it.  The time-consuming part is sorting the two tables inside their cursors, which is O(nlog(n)) and O(mlog(m)).  The comparison of the two is linear [ O(n+m) ].

Hopefully, your database manager has a procedural scripting language that will make this easy.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm following. I guess I should add that in my real problem I'm currently comparing 30 columns, not just 1. And taking the sum of all the comparisons: abs(t1.val_n-t2.val_n). So I think that might make this approach more difficult? But I can use python, so it might be easier in a dataframe