# I want to replicate sql OUTER APPLY functinally in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to replicate what "OUTER APPLY" function in pyspark.

Here are my example data frames

```
## Deparment table
data = [
    (1,'Engineering'),
    (2,'Administration'),
    (3,'Sales'),
    (4,'Marketing'),
  (5,'Finance')
]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('DepartmentID', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('Name', StringType(), True)
])

Department = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema =schema) 
Department.show()

+------------+--------------+
|DepartmentID|          Name|
+------------+--------------+
|           1|   Engineering|
|           2|Administration|
|           3|         Sales|
|           4|     Marketing|
|           5|       Finance|
+------------+--------------+

## Employee table
data = [
    (1,'Orlando', 'Gee', 1),
    (2,'Keith', 'Harris', 2),
     (3,'Donna', 'Carreras', 3),
     (4,'Janet', 'Gates', 3),
]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('EmployeeID', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('FirstName', StringType(), True),
  StructField('LastName', StringType(), True),
  StructField('DepartmentID', IntegerType(), True),
  
])
Employee = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema =schema) 
Employee.show()
+----------+---------+--------+------------+
|EmployeeID|FirstName|LastName|DepartmentID|
+----------+---------+--------+------------+
|         1|  Orlando|     Gee|           1|
|         2|    Keith|  Harris|           2|
|         3|    Donna|Carreras|           3|
|         4|    Janet|   Gates|           3|
+----------+---------+--------+------------+
```

I tried creating a temp table and use a spark SQL command to query as we normally do on temporary tables...  but I keep getting

`[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'OUTER'(line 3, pos 2)

== SQL ==

SELECT * FROM Department D
OUTER APPLY
--^^^
(
SELECT * FROM Employee E
WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
) A
`

error. Any help is appreciated.

```
Employee.createOrReplaceTempView("Employee")
Department.createOrReplaceTempView("Department")

sql_query = """
  SELECT * FROM Department D 
  OUTER APPLY 
    ( 
      SELECT * FROM Employee E 
      WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID 
    ) A
"""

result_df = sqlContext.sql(sql_query)
```

Comment: Looks like this may have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561455/how-to-use-outer-apply-in-spark-sql

Answer (score 0):

OUTER APPLY is a SQL Server native capability (OUTER clause + APPLY operator), and there is no direct simmilar command in spark. Even if you use Spark SQL, you commands will not work either.

However, in order to simulate a similar behaviour you can use LEFT JOIN LATERAL if you wanna have the subquery capability (see example below)

```
SELECT id, name, deptno, deptname
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT deptname
                     FROM department
                     WHERE employee.ID= department.ID);
```

OR you will need to save your queries into two dataframes and use LEFT ANTI (or left outer)

```
employee_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM employee")
department_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM department")
result_df = employee_df.join(department_df, ["ID"], "leftanti") # will pick up all rows existing only in employee with all columns from employee as well. 
# Considering that ID is the same column name in both tables you can use the [] expression
```